# how to display data from one page to another using hyperlink in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Hi all I was designing web application in that i have two master pages `Default.aspx` and `Addregistration.aspx` in `addregistration` i stored the data in database using `SQL` and i display data in default page as a `gridview` and I made my column as `hyperlink in grid view` when I click that link it should go to `addregistration page`  how I store the data with fields and text what I type.Below is the Css for column

Comment: Here's the logic, get **ID/ReferenceNo** from querystring(do check for null or empty string). Once the ID/ReferenceNo is received you need to get data from database by particular id. You can use datareader, dataset or datatable to read and store data then one by one whatever control you have in your view page bind to that.

Comment: Can you tell me the code which I post is correct or not??

Comment: I doubt that the code you have shared has anything to do with what I have mentioned in my comment and Here you have filtered data by `OwnerDepartment` while in your post you told you need to filter data by `ReferenceNo` that's what you sending in querystring.

Comment: I used OwnerDepartment to search from dropdownlist to display data in gridview I am using ReferenceNo as to link between two pages.

Answer (score 0):

Handle it by javascript. Your NavigateUrl is #, and add an onclick event, Or just use an input type button to make it easier

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hlink" CssClass="control" runat="server" NavigateUrl='#' onclick="gotoRegistration(<%#Bind("ReferenceNo")%>)" Text='<%#Bind("ReferenceNo")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

try there to pass the ReferenceNo to the JS function, if Bind doesn't work, try Eval.
and your JS

```
<script>
 function gotoRegistration(theRefNo)
{
theUrl = "~/AddRegistration.aspx?refNo="+ theRefNo
   window.location = theUrl;
}

</script>
```

And then your Registration page read it from Query of the Request

Comment: I already tried this it dint work for me. can u suggest any other one.

Comment: which part didn't work? the javascript or the Hyperlink or where?

Comment: Can I have viewcode in vb.net and where should I apply this JS??

Comment: You can put the script bloc anywhere in your aspx page, better in the bottom. You can debug the javascript code with Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I), see if it's fired or not

Comment: Server tag is not formed correctly got this error in css

Comment: Look at the generated code of the  <asp:HyperLink ID="hlink" CssClass="control" runat="server" NavigateUrl='#' onclick="gotoRegistration(<%#Bind("ReferenceNo")%>)" Text='<%#Bind("ReferenceNo")%>'></asp:HyperLink>, adjust is depending the error

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Page.PreviousPage Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage(v=vs.110).aspx) to get data or access controls at *Default.aspx* from *Addregistration.aspx*

sample code in Addregistration.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hlink")
}
```